# How to display custom data array via Twig

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I've created service which gets the raw data from custom content type. It looks like this :

```
  Array
(
    [front_page_slider] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                    [body] =>Some example slider text up here
                    [field_image] => http://localhost/drupal8/sites/default/files/2016-05/slider1.png
                    [field_link_uri] => http://example.com
                    [field_link_title] => see more
                )

        )

)
```

After that i use array_push function to add this array $variables global variable.

I've tried to display any of this fields like this:

```
{{ dump(front_page_slider[1].title) }}
```

or this:
  {{ dump(front_page_slider) }}

But both return NULL. What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added 'front_page_slider to the variables array in your twig template definition?

File...module_name.module

```
function hook_theme(array $existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'template_name' => [
          'variables' => [
           'front_page_slider' => [],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: Where should I create this .module file ? In the theme directory ?

Comment: Yes. Your main directory should contain a module_name.info.yml, module_name.module, and your template directory.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Devel Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) (also enable devel kint sub module)and use **kint**

**What is Kint?**

> Kint for PHP is a tool designed to present your debugging data in the absolutely best way possible.
>
> In other words, it's var_dump() and debug_backtrace() on steroids. Easy to use, but powerful and customizable. An essential addition to
>   your development toolbox.
>
> This module allows to use kint($data) like as dpm()/dsm()/krumo() in
>   Devel module.

something like
           {{ kint(page) }}

[Read more  and some usage about kint](https://drupalize.me/blog/201405/lets-debug-twig-drupal-8).